# wall updates can be seen only by friends

Tags: php, rows, social-networking, friend

i'm creating a wall system where you can post updates  on the index page  and i wanted the posts to be seen only by friends of the user, i almost made my code work  but i still have a problem ,but before i mention my problem if there is a better way to do it please share it with me , i will show you my code

first i have two tables for the code

'my_friends' : 'id' ,'username','friend'

'statues' : 'p_id','post','f_name','userip','date_created'

this code is in post.php then it will be included in the index page

```
    //Check for user's friends
    $check = mysql_query("select * from `my_friends` where `username` = '".$username."' order by `id` desc ");


        //Get users friends
        while($get_users_friends = mysql_fetch_array($check))
        {


            $show_more_button = 1;
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT *,
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - date_created AS TimeSpent FROM `statues` WHERE  `f_name` = '".mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($get_users_friends["friend"]))."' ");
        }

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{


    $comments = mysql_query("SELECT *,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - date_created AS CommentTimeSpent FROM comments where post_id = ".$row['p_id']." order by c_id asc");     ?>
   <div class="friends_area" id="record-<?php  echo $row['p_id']?>">


       <label style="float:left" class="name">

       <b><?php echo $row['f_name'];  ?></b><br>
       <span>

       </span><br>

       <em><?php  echo $row['post'];?></em>
       <br clear="all" />
```

the code doesn't work right, it show the post feed to only one friend, the first added friend of the user ,in other words , the sql `$result = mysql_query("SELECT *,
                UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - date_created AS TimeSpent FROM`statues`WHERE`f_name`= '".mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($get_users_friends["friend"]))."' ");` select all the statues of only one friend ,when i write `echo mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($get_users_friends["friend"])),'<br>';` before the sql it shows all the friends but when i use it in the sql it doesn't, please help

Answer (score 0):

Here are some thoughts that maybe can help you

1. Dont use `mysql_*` functions they are deprecated use `PDO` class instead
2. Dont query for * if you dont need whole the information from the table
3. Table name is `statues`
4. After completing first while your variable $result will hold only the last friend data query cause it gets overritten by the next step of iteration(use `$result[] =` )
5. Aggregate info from $get_users_friends to rewrite your query into `SELECT p_id, post, f_name, UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - date_created AS TimeSpent FROM statues WHERE f_name IN '.implode(',', $firends_name)`.
6. Dont see if you use $comments variable at all
7. $show_more_button = 1; dont see if it is used at all. and ofc it gets overritten by next iteration step;

your code should look something like:

```
$check = mysql_query("select friend from `my_friends` where `username` = '".$username."' order by `id` desc ");

while($get_users_friends = mysql_fetch_array($check, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{           
    $result[] = $get_users_friends['friend'];
}
$friends_data_query = mysql_query("SELECT p_id, f_name, post,UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - date_created AS TimeSpent FROM `statues` WHERE  `f_name` IN'".implode(',',$result)."'");
while($friends_data = mysql_fetch_array($friends_data_query,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
```

But make sure that it is rewritten into PDO. Cause now it is very vulnurable to injections.

Comment: OP is asking about privacy and had given such a title to question that it appears in top of search results but it gives no details even not in your answer about what actually is the question.